# One project with two forms inside, build two separate exe files for each form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

This is the question, have two forms in one VS2010 project, want to have output of separate .exe files for each form? Any suggestions?
 Forms are sharing the same data, but have different functionality..

Comment: that's why I asked this question, you think there is now way of doing that?

Comment: You can build your EXEs using the [command line compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd(v=vs.100).aspx) for each form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, you could use two different build configurations and pre-processor definitions and separate build configurations, but I can't think of a single instance where this would be good thing to do.

Instead, you'll probably want to separate your code into 3 projects.  Two forms applications, and 1 library.  Put the code that is common between them into the library.

Comment: that's what I did before, things went to complicated, just decided to check if there easier way...

Comment: +1 for showing standard approach to such problem. @Stanislav, if splitting project in 3 separate pieces is hard any non-standard way of building 2 executable with single project would  likely cause more issues than it worth.

Comment: @Stanislav Can you elaborate on too complicated?