# Create an auxilary program (.exe file) to my main program in one solution?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have an application that is automatically shut down when a certain event occurs.
When the application is shut down this way the very last thing my application does is to tell Windows to shut down as well.
The shutdown of Windows is done by calling the following:

```
private void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If class level flag set shut down Windows with a delay of xx seconds
        if (shutdownWindowsOnExit)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 30");

    }
```

The user must be able to cancel the shutdown of Windows after my application has shut down, which is why the delay of 30 seconds is defined.
To accomplish this I just placed a regular shortcut on the desktop, which then called the following when pressed (cancels Windows shutdown):

```
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /a
```

What I want is to get rid of the shortcut and implement the canceling code in something that appears (for the user) to belong to my application (that has just been closed).

I have considered to simply create a small separate application which would consist of a form with a button stating "Press here to cancel Windows shutdown".
I could then start this small application from my main application right after calling

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 30");
```

This way I would be very sure that my main application was safely shutdown, and that only the small auxilary application would be terminated by Windows upon Windows shutdown.

I know that one can comprise two projects in one solution in Visual Studio, but it feels a bit overkill to create a separate project (with settings.settings file, app.config file, version control etc.) to create this little auxilary program.

**My question now is:**
Can I in some way code and compile this separate form to a separate .exe file within my existing project in Visual Studio, without the need of two complete separate projects in one solution.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Why not just make a new Form with-in the same project?

Comment: Because my main application is completely closed during the 30 seconds where cancellation must be possible.

Comment: Why is that though? Why not do the following flow :1) Perform all needed shutdown processes (minus killing the app), 2) close the main form and open new form 3) give user time to cancel shutdown on new form4.A) if user selects nothing shutdown is started and app is killed 4.B) if user cancels shutdown app is killed but no shut down command

Comment: possible duplicate of [One project with two forms inside, build two separate exe files for each form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821256/one-project-with-two-forms-inside-build-two-separate-exe-files-for-each-form)

Comment: It sounds like a good flow, but I want to make sure, that the user is not presented with any messages like "The application was not shut down properly..." when my application is started next time.

Comment: that could indicate that the real solution is to correctly terminate any background thread that is still running.  It's hard to tell without looking at code though. Either way the answer would not be 2 exes.

Comment: I never had the issue with the message I talked about, but I could imagine this could happen. I leave the question open while I work on your suggestion.

Comment: OK, I did the change you suggested, and it works perfect so far. Can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do the following flow :

1. Perform all needed shutdown processes (minus killing the app),
2. Close the main form and open new form with a timer and a cancel button
3. When timer is up kill the application and shutdown windows
4. If the user cancels kill the application but do not shutdown windows

when terminating the application ensure no background threads are still running to avoid

> "The application was not shut down properly"

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes you need someone to tell you that you are on the wrong track.